# how to invoke a backing bean in the EJB module

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, facelets

When I run the application, the counter increments as intended, but how do I move the bean from the web module to the ejb module?

General structure:

```
NetBeansProjects/EntAppWeb/
├── build.xml
├── EntAppWeb-ejb
│   ├── build.xml
│   ├── nbproject
│   │   ├── ant-deploy.xml
│   │   ├── build-impl.xml
│   │   ├── genfiles.properties
│   │   ├── private
│   │   │   ├── private.properties
│   │   │   └── private.xml
│   │   ├── project.properties
│   │   └── project.xml
│   └── src
│       ├── conf
│       │   └── MANIFEST.MF
│       └── java
├── EntAppWeb-war
│   ├── build.xml
│   ├── nbproject
│   │   ├── ant-deploy.xml
│   │   ├── build-impl.xml
│   │   ├── genfiles.properties
│   │   ├── private
│   │   │   ├── private.properties
│   │   │   └── private.xml
│   │   ├── project.properties
│   │   └── project.xml
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── conf
│   │   │   └── MANIFEST.MF
│   │   └── java
│   │       └── dur
│   │           ├── database
│   │           │   ├── Clients.java
│   │           │   ├── ClientsQueryBean.java
│   │           │   └── QueryBeanWithEntityManager.java
│   │           └── facelets
│   │               ├── DirectoryBean.java
│   │               ├── Hello.java
│   │               └── MyQueueBean.java
│   └── web
│       ├── eagle.xhtml
│       ├── falcon.xhtml
│       ├── index.xhtml
│       ├── menu.xhtml
│       ├── next.xhtml
│       ├── parrot.xhtml
│       ├── template.xhtml
│       └── WEB-INF
│           └── web.xml
├── LICENSE
├── nbproject
│   ├── ant-deploy.xml
│   ├── build-impl.xml
│   ├── genfiles.properties
│   ├── private
│   │   └── private.properties
│   ├── project.properties
│   └── project.xml
├── README.md
└── src
    └── conf
        └── MANIFEST.MF
```

How the `EAR` builds:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ jar -tf NetBeansProjects/EntAppWeb/dist/EntAppWeb.ear 
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
lib/
EntAppWeb-ejb.jar
EntAppWeb-war.war
lib/javaee-api-7.0.jar
thufir@dur:~$
```

the facelet:

```
<!DOCTYPE    html  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0  Transitional//EN"  
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head></h:head>
    <h:body>
        This and everything before will be ignored
        <ui:composition template="template.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="navigation">
                <ui:include src="menu.xhtml"/>
            </ui:define>
            <ui:define name="main">
                <h1>bird</h1>
                next   #{myQueueBean.next}
            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
        This and everything after will be ignored
    </h:body>
</html>
```

and the bean:

```
package dur.facelets;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
//import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Named
@ApplicationScoped
@Singleton
public class MyQueueBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyQueueBean.class.getName());
    private int next = 1001;

    public MyQueueBean() {
    }

    public int getNext() {
        log.info("next\t" + next);
        return next++;
    }
}
```

full source:

https://github.com/THUFIR/EntAppWeb

Comment: You're not supposed to put web (frontend) artifacts in business/service layer (backend).

Comment: can you explain that a bit?  maybe I should've asked a different question.

Comment: He means the EJB is not supposed to be aware of the JSF managed bean; the reverse should be the case. Is there any particular reason you're trying to implement the EJB and the managed bean as the same class @Thufir?

Comment: @kolossus  pardon, which class are you referring to?

Comment: I'm talking about `MyQueueBean`. Why is it annotated as an EJB as well as a JSF managed bean?

Comment: I'll take a look; I've, of course, changed the code a bit.  Is the idea that there should be an EJB in the EJB module, and a **seperate** `@Named` backing bean?